# regular expressions cut from the second pipe

Tags: regex, expression

Using java regular expressions basically to reduce a list of semicolon separated properties

```
2013-07-15 21:46:26|Dinner with James|Lucerne|MEDIATYPE;image|CATEGORY;25|365|423|IMGTOKEN;8adbfb5840349cac014052ded00f26da|TAGS;dinner|james|lucerne;
```

What I am trying to achieve is to:

1. strip all characters after the next semicolon;
2. cut the word before the semicolon (in this example `MEDIATYPE`);
3. cut the pipe

Expected end result:

```
2013-07-15 21:46:26|Dinner with James|Lucerne
```

How could I do that with regular expressions?

Solved! Thanks! `(.*?)(?=\|[^|;]+;)` worked out for me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It seems that you need to visit the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and refer to help on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to split on the the pipe (`|`) before the semi-colon?

This pattern will work:

```
\\|(?=[^|]*;)
```

Explanation

- `\\|` a literal pipe character. The double escape is Java syntax
- `(?=[^|]*;)` this is a lookahead assertion that finds a semi-colon that follows the pipe. There are any number of non-pipe characters before the semi-colon.

Example:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final String input = "2013-07-15 21:46:26|Dinner with James|Lucerne|MEDIATYPE;image|CATEGORY;25|365|423|IMGTOKEN;8adbfb5840349cac014052ded00f26da|TAGS;dinner|james|lucerne;";
    final String[] split = input.split("\\|(?=[^|]*;)");
    System.out.println(split[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
2013-07-15 21:46:26|Dinner with James|Lucerne
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use a replace, matching on the first pipe that is immediately followed by a semicolon. The raw regex string I suggest is:

```
\|(?=[^|;]*;).*
```

Which is this in Java string:

```
\\|(?=[^|;]*;).*
```

An example:

```
String text = "2013-07-15 21:46:26|Dinner with James|Lucerne|MEDIATYPE;image|CATEGORY;25|365|423|IMGTOKEN;8adbfb5840349cac014052ded00f26da|TAGS;dinner|james|lucerne;";
String result = text.replaceAll("\\|(?=[^|;]*;).*", "");
System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

which should give you:

```
2013-07-15 21:46:26|Dinner with James|Lucerne
```

Breakdown:

```
\\|      Match a literal pipe
(?=      Begin positive lookahead
  [^|;]* Any character except pipe or semicolon
  ;      A semicolon
)        End positive lookahead
.*       Anything else on this line
```

The positive lookahead is ensuring that there is a semicolon right after the pipe where the 'cut' begins without any more pipe or semicolons in between.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

```
(.*?)(?=\|[^|;]+;)
```

[Example](http://regex101.com/r/sQ6iN2)